# Postgres 9.6 Syntax Error on Begin Transaction errors due to semi colon;

Tags: postgresql

Am using Postgres 9.6 and have a transaction which I am looking to run on a large data set 889m rows.

I am looking to delete older data from the game table thats older than 1 year but retain the deleted row data in a separate table. To make it more robust wrapped it within a transaction, dropping the indexes prior to doing to minimise bloat.

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE public.gamearchived (LIKE public.game);

DROP INDEX public.idx_game_game_created_on, public.idx_game_session_id, public.game_idx_01, public.game_idx_game_id;

WITH del AS (
   DELETE FROM game
   WHERE  game_created_on < NOW() - interval '1 year';  -- older than 1 year
   RETURNING *
   )
 , ins AS (
   INSERT INTO public.gamearchived
   SELECT * FROM del
   ORDER  BY game_id ; 
    )
SELECT count(*) FROM del;  -- get your count

COMMIT;
```

I am getting a syntax error

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near ";"
  Position: 90
```

Cant understand why its not parsing. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Remove the semi-colon from there `ORDER  BY game_id ;` - they can't be inside CTEs!

Comment: PostgreSQL is EOL (End Of Life) in ~ 2 weeks - you should think about an upgrade!

Comment: @Vérace even after removing the semi-colon at the order by still has an issue.

Comment: @Vérace removed it from the WHERE  game_created_on < NOW() - interval '1 year'; also, did not know semi-colons could not be in CTEs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole paragraph starting with `WITH` and exnding with `SELECT count(*) FROM del` is a single SQL statement.

Unless it is in a string literal or in the body of a standard conforming SQL function definition, you cannot have a semicolon inside an SQL statement. Semicolons are used to separate different statements in SQL.